# Why can't I import "react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css"?

Tags: css, reactjs, import, sidebar

I want to add the css file "react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css" in my jsx file. But when I try, there's an error. I've already installed react-pro-sidebar and all the essentials...

Thanks in advance.

I wanted to implement a Sidebar to a project and followed a tutorial. I did the same like in the video (12.10.2022) but I have the error that it can't import the file.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you are using version 1.0.0 of react-pro-sidebar. This version does not include a .css file to import, as css-in-js is now the preferred styling method according to the docs: https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar.

If you want to use the imported css file you can downgrade to v0.7.1 of react-pro-sidebar, but i recommend using the newest version and either use inline styling or overriding the css like this:

```
//sidebar container
.ps-sidebar-root{
    position: sticky !important;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 0 !important;
}

//sidebar text color
.ps-menu-root{
    color: red !important;
}

//hover over menuitems color
.ps-menu-button:hover {
    background-color: red  !important;
    color: black  !important;
}

//text and background color for submenu
.ps-submenu-content {
    color: black !important;
    background-color: red  !important;
}
```